# modx почему именно так

Tags: cms, modx, revo

Ссть сниппет:

```
<?php
$usid = $modx->user->get('id');
$sql='';
$sql = "SELECT distinct modx_site_content.*, status.value as status, ispoln.value as ispoln, cat_phot.value as cat_phot,
cat_model.value as cat_model, interier_type.value as interier_type, modx_is_read.is_read, date_godno.value as date_godno, date_godno_predl.value as date_godno_predl FROM `modx_site_content` 
inner join modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues  status on status.tmplvarid=22
and contentid=modx_site_content.id 
and status.`value` IN (2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
left join modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues  ispoln on  ispoln.tmplvarid=28 and ispoln.contentid=modx_site_content.id 
left join modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues  date_godno on  date_godno.tmplvarid=40 and date_godno.contentid=modx_site_content.id
left join modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues  date_godno_predl on  date_godno_predl.tmplvarid=41 and date_godno_predl.contentid=modx_site_content.id";

$sql.="left join modx_is_read on idres=modx_site_content.id and  iduser=".$modx->user->get('id')." ";

$sql.="left join modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues  cat_phot on  cat_phot.tmplvarid=15 and cat_phot.contentid=modx_site_content.id 
left join modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues  cat_model on  cat_model.tmplvarid=17 and cat_model.contentid=modx_site_content.id 
left join modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues  interier_type on  interier_type.tmplvarid=29 and interier_type.contentid=modx_site_content.id ";

$sql.="where deleted=0 and ispoln.value=".$modx->user->get('id')." or createdby=".$modx->user->get('id')."";

$statement  = $modx->query($sql);
$mas =$statement ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

На сайте вот такая ошибка:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/vhosts/u0005768.plsk.regruhosting.ru/photo.ulikes.ru/core/cache/includes/elements/modsnippet/288.include.cache.php
>   on line 37

Если я перед переменной укажу вот так `echo $usid;`, то ошибки нет.

Подскажите, что не так и где я ошибся?

Comment: Вы уверены, что в сформированном вручную запросе вы не допустили ошибок? Данное сообщение возникло скорее всего по нему, что у вас ошибка в SQL-запросе.

Comment: я выполнил в mysql этот запрос и все работает

Comment: разобрался, в запросе при выполнение склеилась строка без пробела

Comment: У Вас ошибка в самой концепции запроса - в модиксе не делаются такие километровые запросы в сыром виде. Учите xpdo и будет Вам счастье.